# UITableViewCell delete on swipe animation ugly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following problem. When I delete UITableViewCells from my UITableView with "swipe to delete" I see an ugly behaviour of the UITableView. Regardless which animation I choose in the deleteRows method all deletions result in the same strange behaviour.

This is my code for deleting the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")

        self.tvItems.beginUpdates()

        if(indexPath.section == 0){
            Shoppingcart.shared.removeItemForId(ident: indexPath.row)
        }else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            Shoppingcart.shared.serviceContent.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }

        if let parent = self.parent as? CollectionViewController{
            parent.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
        self.tvItems.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        self.tvItems.endUpdates()

    }
}
```

Here is an image of the broken animation:

[image: See the broken animation here]

Comment: what is the relation between `parent.collectionView` and `tableView`?

Comment: The tableview is inside an modal viewcontroller on top of the CollectionViewController. The tableview represents a shoppingcart while the collectionview in the background is the shop overview. If an item gets removed from the shoppingcart is should be updated inside the collectionview so it's no longer marked as an item which is already added to the shopping cart. You can ignore this line. The animation is still broken even if I remove this line

Comment: try to change from `.fade` to `.left`

Comment: I have alreay tried all animations including .left .
The animation does not change at all no matter what I choose for one it. It remains exactly the same misconduct. The animation must actually change anyway or not?

Comment: try removing the reload datas and work form the start again,  also check the code being run when you remove stuff from your singleton cart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. The tableviewcell hight estimation was set on automatic. I did set the hight on the same as the row height and the broken animation disappeared.

Settings for the broken animation:

[image: Wrong]

Settings for the working animation:

[image: Right]

Answer (score 0):

I had A LOT of trouble with this. Moving completion(true) to the top instead of at the bottom solved the problem. Hope it helps someone out there!

```
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        completion(true) // *** PUT THIS HERE!!! ****
        self.searchFoodView.beginUpdates()
        self.foodMachine.deleteFood(at: indexPath.row - 1)
        self.searchFoodView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.searchFoodView.endUpdates()
    })
```